# Resizing images in column layout with css

Tags: css, html, image

I'm trying to create a web page with a two column layout. One aspect of it, is that images can be resized to take up half the column width. I use some CSS as follows

```
.columnWrapper {
  float: left;
  width: auto;  
}
.sidebar1 {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
}
.main {
  float: left;
  width: 66%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: solid 1px rgb(153,153,153);
}

footer {
  clear: both;  
}
nav ul, header h1, footer p, .contentWrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;   
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;  
}
img.half {
  max-width: 50%;   
}
img.left {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
img.right {
  float: right; 
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

When I try to resize the images in the html using markup like the following

```
<div class="contentWrapper"> 
<div class="columnWrapper">
<!-- main content goes here -->
<article class="main">
  <img src="images/synergy2.jpg" alt="Synergy" class="half right">
  <h3>About us</h3>
  <p>blah blah blah</p>
</article>
<!-- first sidebar goes here -->
<aside class="sidebar1">
</aside>
<!-- end column wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- end content wrapper -->
</div>
```

It works as I expected on Chrome, but Firefox has a problem, in that the image isn't resized. Is there a problem with the CSS or is it a browser issue? Thanks.

Another thing I was wondering, is there a simple way to make sure that the columns have a minimum height. If there isn't much content the footer ends up too high and looks strange. Thanks.

I put up a sample web page with the html / css in question
http://adjk3543.appspot.com/aboutus.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a width to your columnWrapper:

```css
.columnWrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution works. But why doesn't the width: auto; work in the original CSS ?

Comment: I believe it is to do with `float` needing a set width. If you remove `float` from your `columnWrapper` (along with `width`) it will also work fine. Here is some reading on the topic: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

I too found the same solution as @3dgoo has given. So Adding footer solution here too. You have to do some CSS hack to align footer at bottom always irrespective of content on page.

Check this out [CSS Stick Footer](http://cssstickyfooter.com)

This definitely works. I have used many times. 
Make sure you understand the logic here.